# Eclipse unable to clean build output

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I have an Eclipse (4.4.1) working set consisting of ~60 projects (the number may be relevant, as it takes more time to refresh the workspace). Occasionally, I encounter build failures because Eclipse is unable to clean the output folder before build:

[image: Eclipse build problem]

It turned out that the process which locks the file is Eclipse itself:

[image]

It also turned out that files being locked are always of XML content. Particularly, if I define resources with `*.foo` extension as XML files (via **Preferences -> General -> Content Types**), there's a good chance they will be locked, too, once they're copied to the output path.

I thought the problem was caused by all XML resources being validated automatically:

[image]

-- so I added exclusion filters 1st and even disabled XML/XSD validation entirely. The problem stopped occurring that often, but still emerges from time to time. Refreshing or closing-reopening a project isn't helpful.

The only remedy is restarting Eclipse or running [Unlocker](http://emptyloop.com/unlocker/) every 1/2 hour, which is not very convenient.

Any ideas how to solve or at least further diagnose this?

Comment: this sounds like an excellent question to ask the Eclipse community, as it sounds very much like a bug in Eclipse.

Comment: As a possible cause, check the TaskManager for any additional java.exe processes that are active during the failed builds. I believe I had a similar issue once.

Comment: does "Suspend all validators" work for you? I know this is risky, but do you really want to validate all the xml all the time?

Comment: @hagubear Tried that already. Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Just my 2 cents.

Perhaps you can fix this issue by following this steps:

1. Project -> Properties -> Builders -> New -> Program
2. Define a custom "Cleaner"-Program, for example *Unlocker* or your own Java- or CMD-script
3. Move your custom Builder-Program up. **It should be the first Builder in the list**

*P.S. some times i have similar problems caused by Avira Antivirus Scanner...*

Answer (score 2):

Disable third-party version control daemons. (Like TGitCache).

They only lock resources for a short while and are not visible in Process Explorer, but are the most frequent cause of such failures.

Comment: That was my idea, too. So I disabled `TGitCache.exe` and even "un-shared" my projects. Still, the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that XML Validation is the main cause of your problem, I suggest you extend your search for validation points in your projects' configuration, to set off all of them:

- General preferences/Validation
- General preferences/XML/XML files/Validation (the "honour all schema locations" option might be causing delay at validating)
- Project preferences/Validation (check them; might be overriding the general preferences)
- Project preferences/Builders/Validator

Hope it helps.

Comment: Excuse me, Bass, but I don't understand: If my answer was not useful to you, I guess you awarded me with the bounty by mistake.

Comment: No, no mistake. I believe your answer was the closest to the truth. There's a problem with WST/WTP, and XML Validation is a feature of this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar issues. Yes, the number of projects is probably the cause.  Close the projects not in use. If that cleans things up moving groups of related project into separate work spaces should help you out.

i.e File-> Close project

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The problem is that I'm actually _using_ those projects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the problem, but I would tackle the problem this way:

1. download [File Leak Detector](http://file-leak-detector.kohsuke.org/)
2. add the agentpath to your eclipse.ini (e.g., 
   -javaagent:*path/to/file-leak-detector.jar*=http=19999, see documentation of File Leak Detector)
3. when the problem happens again, see which (eclipse) class is responsible for holding a handle of the file
4. Find out what is the purpose of the class that holds the handle

This way, you are maybe able to pin down the Eclipse feature that causes your problem.

Comment: Thanks, _File Leak Detector_ is probably a great tool, but on my PC it crashes any JVM it attempts to connect to.